# É possível fazer autenticação/validação de formulário com Node.js puro?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hoje me interessei pelo Node.js pelo fato de poder programar javascript no back-end e front-end.

Pelo que eu entendi - corrijam-me se eu estiver errado - o Node é uma plataforma que me permite criar aplicações server-side usando JavaScript.

Procurando por tutoriais de como resgatar dados de um formulário ou como autenticar um usuário, só achei resultados usando Express ou outro framework.

É possível fazer isso com Node puro? Pesquisei na documentação do Node mas não achei nada relacionado.

Comment: Costumo utilizar esse validator: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-validator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A maneira mais comum é usando o [Express](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html) e um dos seus plugins [BodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) para converter um formulário por exemplo num objeto fácil de trabalhar.

Tendo em conta que ambos são escritos em JavaScript é possivel fazer com código nativo, ou seja "re-inventar a roda". Eu desaconselho. O conceito do Node é ir à [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) buscar os módulos todos que se precise para tornar o código mais fácil de escrever, uma vez que se trata de um servidor o desempenho a carregar esse módulos é irrelevante pois carregam antes de se iniciar o servidor.

Mas respondendo à tua pergunta aqui fica:

```
http = require('http');
fs = require('fs');
server = http.createServer( function(req, res) {

    console.dir(req.param);
    console.log(req.method);
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
        console.log("Partial body: " + body);
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        console.log("Body: " + body);
        // aqui podes usar o body, com
        var dados = JSON.parse(body);
        // etc...
        // enviar a resposta para o browser:
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end('post received'); // ou outra mensagem de validação
    });
});

port = 3000;
host = '127.0.0.1';
server.listen(port, host);
console.log('Listening at http://' + host + ':' + port);
```

Comment: tem como você colocar um exemplo com um servidor real?