# É possível fazer validação de formulário no cliente e no servidor somente com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, formulário

No caso em particular, gostaria de criar um `form` para contato, com nome, tipo de serviço (menu dropdown: webdesign, mobile), assunto e mensagem. Gostaria também de enviar esse `form` com nome, tipo de serviço e mensagem para um e-mail específico no formato de texto.

Normalmente a validação de um `form` é feita no servidor com ASP, Java. Agora, seria possível fazer validação somente com JavaScript? Qual a tecnologia necessária para fazer isso?

Comment: A parte de javascript tinha feito em baixo mas o envio do do email tem sempre de ser feito do lado servidor. Com php/ASP etc..

Comment: Node é servidor, AngularJS não é

Comment: Conheço sim, mas quer fazer as validações do lado cliente em javascript? (como fiz em baixo) Ou do lado servidor... Só o lado servidor que consegue enviar emails, seja ele em node/php/etc..

Comment: Veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102522/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-fazer-autentica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-formul%C3%A1rio-com-node-js-puro?rq=1 pode ser q ajude. E isto https://nodemailer.com/

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101

Comment: Paulo , veja este plugin para jquery : https://jqueryvalidation.org

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar a validação Client-Side com Javascript (puro ou usando alguma bilioteca como JQuery, AngularJS, etc).
Esta vai ocorrer antes de você enviar os dados para o servidor. Algo assim:

```
function Valida() {
    if (document.getElementById("nome").value.length < 1) {
        alert("Digite um nome.");
        document.getElementById("nome").focus();
        return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById("idade").value.length < 1) {
        alert("Digite uma idade.");
        document.getElementById("idade").focus();
        return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById("sexo").value == 0) {
        alert("Escolha um sexo.");
        document.getElementById("sexo").focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Fonte: https://bytecrow.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/tutorial-para-iniciantes-05-validacao-de-formulario-com-javascript/

Você pode (e recomendo) fazer a validação também no lado servidor usando NodeJS e Javascript.

O código é grande, veja em https://udgwebdev.com/trabalhando-com-validators-no-node-js.

Dá para mandar e-mails txt ou html usando o nodemailer, plugin para express:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://user%40gmail.com:pass@smtp.gmail.com');

// setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
var mailOptions = {
    from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@blurdybloop.com>', // sender address
    to: 'bar@blurdybloop.com, baz@blurdybloop.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ', // plaintext body
    html: '<b>Hello world </b>' // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```

Fonte: https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer

Comment: O que aconteceria no caso do JS estar desabilitado em meu browser?

Comment: @MagicHat o céu cairia sobre a Terra.

Comment: @renan hehe, falando sério...

Comment: Enviaria o formulário normalmente, independente de inserir (ou não) qualquer informação nos campos. A pergunta que o bigown linkou nos comentários é uma boa: [Usar validação via cliente é suficiente?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/4808)

Comment: suspeitei desde o princípio....

Comment: Se o Javascript estiver desabilitado, o browser consegue enviar os dados (se não tiver usando ajax para isso). No lado servidor tudo ocorrerá normalmente. O que não vai acontecer é a validação no client-side.